# Write a query to find all the views in a specific schema which is making use of two tables that are in a different schema in snowflake

Tags: sql, view, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Database ( say x_db ) which contains two schemas ( a_db, b_db ). There are two tables t1 and t2 in b_db but this schema doesn't have any views. Can you help me write a query which lists all the views in the a_db schema which uses both the tables t1 and t2 either directly or indirectly in snowflake?

```
select table_catalog as database_name,
table_schema as schema_name,
table_name as view_name,
created
from x_db.information_schema.views
where table_schema= 'a_db' and view_definition LIKE '%t1%' 
                               or view_definition LIKE '%t2%'
                               order by table_name;
```

I have tried this code so far;

Comment: Hi @agems - welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include more details, and anything that you might have tried so far.

Comment: The code in the question looks good so far, I guess what you still need to do is refine the `where view_definition LIKE '%t1%'` clauses. Can you add some sample `view_definition` results from this query, so we can figure out a way to parse the table names from them?

Comment: It's the "indirectly" part of the check for what's using them that can be a challenge. Are you using views on top of views? If so, you'd need to check for any views using the views that use the tables. You'd also have to check for UDFs, UDTFs, and stored procedures using the tables.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question looks good, and now you have to figure out how to parse the table names out of `view_definition`.

An alternative way would be to obtain the plan of running a view.

For example:

```sql
create or replace view delete_view
as select id 
from wikimedia.public.wikidata_by_instance
limit 10;

explain select * from delete_view;

select "objects"
from table(result_scan(last_query_id()))
where "operation"='TableScan'
```

The result is: `WIKIMEDIA.PUBLIC.WIKIDATA_BY_INSTANCE`.

The steps to pull this off would be:

1. Find all views in a schema from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA (you already figured this out).
2. Run a `EXPLAIN SELECT *` for each view (or combine all of them in a join/union).
3. Use the code in this question to scan the objects that go through a TableScan when running the previous explain query.